# Why do I getting false for the isclass function?

Tags: python, class

I'm using the following code to determine whether the input parameter is a class or a variable:

```
class Trajectory():
  ...

print inspect.isclass( Trajectory() )
```

where the Trajectory is a class, but when I'm calling this function I'm receiving false. Why?

According the documentation this have to be true

```
inspect.isclass(object)

    Return true if the object is a class, whether built-in or created in Python code.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `Trajectory()` is a class instance – `Trajectory` is a class.

```
print inspect.isclass(Trajectory)
```

will print `True`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the `isinstance` function.

```
class Test(object): pass

a = Test()
b = 1234

assert isinstance(a, Test)
assert not isinstance(b, Test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are instantiating Trajectory and getting an object instance.  Observe:

```
In [1]: import inspect
In [2]: class Trajectory():
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
In [3]: print inspect.isclass(Trajectory())
False
In [4]: print inspect.isclass(Trajectory)
True
```